# Resourcebundle de_DE и русские символы - иероглифы Java JSP

Tags: java, servlet, локализация

Сделал перевод сайта при помощи `Resourcebundle`. Загружаю его так:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.test.lang", currentLocale);
```

Есть три файла с переводами:

- lang_de_DE.properties;
- lang_en_US.properties;
- lang_ru_RU .properties.

С первыми двумя всё нормально, а вот с языком `DE` нет. В переводе есть русские переводы (временно) и на сайте они отображаются в виде иероглифов. Форматы, кодировки файлов одинаковые. В чём может быть беда?

**EDIT#1**: Так же плохо отображаются символы с двумя точками.
**EDIT#2**: Открыл просто `html` файл, добавили туда текст с точками - всё нормально. При чем даже отображение русских и немецких символов.

Comment: Можете показать где и как Вы загружаете `ResourceBundle` и какие названия у файлов локализации?

Comment: @defaultlocale `lang_de_DE, lang_en_US, lang_ru_RU`  `.properties`

загружаю так: `ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.test.lang", currentLocale);`

Comment: Как инициализируется `currentLocale`? Что если вместо нее подставить `Locale.GERMANY`?

Comment: @defaultlocale парсится заголовок браузера содержащий язык. отдута и берется.

Comment: Проверьте, что в результате получается нужная локаль (язык — de, страна — DE), либо проверьте что получится если заменить на `Locale.GERMANY` если заработает, то значит в парсинге что-то не то.

Comment: @defaultlocale парсинг работает правильно - проверил. `Locale.GERMANY` - не помогает.

Answer (score 2):

Решено этим способом.

```
public class UTF8Control extends Control {
    public ResourceBundle newBundle
        (String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException
    {
        // The below is a copy of the default implementation.
        String bundleName = toBundleName(baseName, locale);
        String resourceName = toResourceName(bundleName, "properties");
        ResourceBundle bundle = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        if (reload) {
            URL url = loader.getResource(resourceName);
            if (url != null) {
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);
                    stream = connection.getInputStream();
                }
            }
        } else {
            stream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
        }
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                // Only this line is changed to make it to read properties files as UTF-8.
                bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
            } finally {
                stream.close();
            }
        }
        return bundle;
    }
}

ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.i18n.text", new UTF8Control());
```

Источник:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle

Спасибо